# How to encode hls playlist with aes key

Tags: video, ffmpeg, aes, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to encode hls playlist with aes key with command:

```
ffmpeg -i v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s1.mp4 -encryption_key 775dbf7289c4cc5847becd571f536ff2 -encryption_kid 800aacaa522958ae888062b5695db6bf -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -vcodec copy stream.m3u8
```

But I get this response:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5649899b9980] could not find corresponding track id 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5649899b9980] could not find corresponding trex
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5649899b9980] error reading header
./angel-one-clear/v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s1.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

This is demo playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="v-0576p-1400k-libx264-init.mp4"
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s1.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s2.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s3.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s4.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s5.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s6.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s7.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s8.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s9.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s10.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s11.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s12.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s13.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s14.mp4
#EXTINF:4.000,
v-0576p-1400k-libx264-s15.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Does anyone have working demo or example for this kind of encoding?